# Invalid URL converting byte array to base64

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signaturepad

Im using signaturepad from Nuget, everything is fine with the exception of trying to recreate signatures from the byte array stored on the server.

My Model has

```
public byte[] MySignature { get; set; }
```

and in my index view I have this to try and display the signature, but all I ever get is invalid urls

```
<td>
        @{
            if (item.MySignature != null)
            {
                <img src="@string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.MySignature));" />
            }
        }
</td>
```

Am I missing something plainly obvious?

Comment: Not quite sure if it's your problem, but the semicolon `;` is not necessary at the end.

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Originally I put it altogether in multiple lines and the ; was just left over from a copy paste. Worked like a charm. If you wanna add an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my guess was right :)

The semicolon at the end of the src attribute value was superfluous:

```
<img src="@string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.MySignature));" />
```

It must be:

```
<img src="@string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.MySignature))" />
```

The reason is that the first one includes the semicolon in the base-64 string, which makes it invalid.